# How to transfer decimal MATICs?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, polygon

I thought the question was simple but I haven't found an answer that was right for my use case... I want to change 3 USD to MATIC. If you do the conversion, that is more or less 3.79 let's say, this is just an example. So the question is simple, how do I transfer this quantity? I've read that I should multiply the number so that there aren't decimals but then the user won't be paying the whole number? For instance, if I multiply the number by 100 so that it's 379, the user won't be paying 379 MATIC which is much more than 3 USD? And if it's like I'm saying, I'm still having an error when trying to do the transfer.

[image]

Thanks a lot because I'm quite lost here.

Some edits to reproduce this error. I'm trying to do this test:

```
it("Get number", async function () {

    var user1Balance = await user1.getBalance();
    console.log("Farmer balance: ", user1Balance);
    var user2Balance = await user2.getBalance();
    console.log("Baker balance: ", user2Balance);

    console.log((await loterya.getLatestPrice() / 10 ** 10) * 10 ** 18 < await user1.getBalance());

    const price = utils.toWei("0.0001");
    await loterya.connect(user1).betNumber(
      user2.address,
      // { value: ethers.utils.parseUnits( (await loterya.getLatestPrice() / 10 ** 10).toString(), "ether") }
      { value: price }
    );

    user1Balance = await user1.getBalance();
    console.log("Farmer balance: ", user1Balance);
    user2Balance = await user2.getBalance();
    console.log("Baker balance: ", user2Balance);

  });
```

Those accounts are: `[contract, user1, user2] = await ethers.getSigners();`

Answer (score 0):

`.transfer(3)` transfers 3 wei from the contract address to the specified address.

Wei is the smallest unit of MATIC. 10^18 (or 1000000000000000000) wei == 1 MATIC.

---

If you want to transfer decimal amount of MATIC, you need to specify the amount in wei.

```
.transfer(500000000000000000);
```

You can also specify the number in scientific form

```
.transfer(5e17);
```

Or you can use the [ether](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/units-and-global-variables.html) unit. Even though you're going to deploy the contract on Polygon, the Solidity syntax is the same for all networks.

```
.transfer(0.5 ether);
```

---

Make sure that the contract has sufficient balance before performing the transfer. Either from already previously preformed transfers to the contract address - or that you're passing at least the intended amount with the transaction that executes your function.

Also note that if the recipient is a contract, it can reject the incoming transfer by not implementing `receive()` nor `fallback()` [special functions](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#special-functions). Or by explicitly throwing a revert inside these functions.

Comment: I still got this error: Error: invalid BigNumber value (argument="value", value={"value":3808772200000000}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.7.0)

Comment: value: ethers.utils.parseUnits( (await loterya.getLatestPrice() / 10 ** 10).toString(), "ether") even trying this is throwing an error:

Comment: Error: invalid BigNumber value (argument="value", value={"value":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x0d880ee202ea00"}}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.7.0)

Comment: @asusrid This set of errors seems to be related to a JavaScript code - not to the Solidity code. Please show a way to reproduce your issue. I.e. what exactly should we do to get the same error as you have.

Comment: I have edited my question to add the code to reproduce the error, if you need anything else tell me. I haven't added the solidity code because as you say, it's not even reaching that point. Thank you Petr!